# How can I write a function result in a <h1> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and right now I'm trying to print the result in an h1 element. With the provided code, how would I do that? My problem is that I don't know how to make a result of a function an `<h1>` element. Right now the result returns a basic `<p>` element.
`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="winner"></h1>
  <input type = "image" onclick="rockSelec()" class="button" src="images/rock.png"></input>
 <input  type = "image" onclick="scisSelec()" class="button" src="images/paper.png"></input>
  <input type = "image" onclick="paperSelec()" class="button" src="images/sci.png"></input>
  
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`style.css`

```css
body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }
  input {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: black;
  }
```

`index.js`

```js
var rock = "Rock";
var paper = "Paper";
var scissors = "Scissors";
var ai = Math.random()*2;
var aib = Math.floor(ai);
var aia;
switch (aib) {
  case 0:
    aia = "Rock";
    break;
  case 1:
    aia = "Paper";
    break; 
  case 2:
    aia = "Scissors";
}
function rps(p1, p2) {
    var win2 = "The winner is p2";
    var win1 = "The winner is p1";
    var draw = "It's a draw"
    if (p1 == "Rock" && p2 == "Paper") 
        return win2;
    if (p1 == "Paper" && p2 == "Rock") 
        returrockSelecn1;
    if (p1 == "Rock" && p2 == "Scissors")
        return win1;
    if (p1 == "Scissors" && p2 == "Rock")
        return win2;
    if (p1 == "Paper" && p2 == "Scissors")
        return win2;
    if (p1 == "Scissors" && p2 == "Paper")
        return win1;
    if (p1 == "Paper" && p2 == "Paper" || p1 == "Rock" && p2 == "Rock" || p1 == "Scissors" && p2 == "Scissors" || p1 == "Rock" && p2 == "Rock")
        return draw;
}
var rockResult = rps(rock, aia);
function rockSelec() {
    return document.write(rps(rock, aia))

}
function paperSelec() {
  return document.write(rps(paper, aia))
}
 
function scisSelec() {
  return document.write(rps(scissors, aia))
}
```

I would not like to change my code too much because I have a set idea of how I want everything.

Comment: `return document.write('<h1>' . rps(scissors, aia) . '</h1>')` perhaps?

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm getting the error: "Identifyer Expected".

Comment: @ceejayoz This is not a valid javascript syntax, I guess you mixed php with javascript

Comment: @HaoWu You're right, mixed up my string concat operators. Heh.

Comment: @c0d3r Use `+` instead of `.`. Oops.

Comment: It worked! If you turn it into an answer, I'll accept it and like it.

Comment: `document.write()` should never be used after page load. You are best off to forget it even exists and learn other more modern insertion and manipulation methods

Comment: @charliefl Which methods?

Comment: There are lots of them. Suggest studying some DOM (Document Object Model) tutorials. Some basics to start with would be `element.innerHTML`, `document.createElement()` , `element.append()`

Comment: I tried `document.createElement()` and `element.innerHTML` and for some reason, the function result didn't print.

Comment: Nevermind, `.innerHTML` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display something between any element here it is (h1) you can use the following method.

First, you need to refer the h1 element to JavaScript file as given below.

```
const refer = document.getElementById('winner');
```

Then, by using innerText, or innerHTML property you can add your result to h1 element.

```
eg: refer.innerText = <variable name which contains your result >
```

Comment: Good, but @ceejayoz answered it better. I prefer to use the `'<h1>' + variable + '</h1>` method. But still a like and a accept bacause no one else wanted to answer.